# How to make the method"executeQuery:query completionHandler:^()" to Sync?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSMutableDictionary * callBackDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];


if(ranges.count > 0){
    GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesBatchGet * query = [GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesBatchGet queryWithSpreadsheetId:sheetID];
    query.ranges = ranges;

    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket * callBackTicket,GTLRSheets_ValueRange * result, NSError * callBackReeor){

        [callBackDic setObject:result forKey:@"result"];
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);


    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    NSLog(@"over");
   return  callBackDic;
```

I want to make the method become sync, but "executeQuery:" never run. I don't know why?

Comment: This is about google sheet API in OC.

Answer (score 1):

In short, don't.   Do not make asynchronous server query methods synchronous.   At best, you're just blocking a background thread for no reason and, at worst, you're making your app unresponsive if that semaphore is on the main thread.

Instead, put your app or threads into whatever idle state desired, then trigger processing the result from the callback block.

I.e. something like this:

```
[self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket * callBackTicket,GTLRSheets_ValueRange * result, NSError * callBackReeor){

    if (!callBackReeor) {
        [self handleServerResult: result];
    } else {
        [self handleServerError: callBackReeor];
    }


}];
```